# What software should I use to build an app that can communicate with SharePoint?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I'm trying to build an app where the user can draw with their finger and have the drawing be placed in an Excel file which is sent to SharePoint. It can either be an android or web application.

1. I need to be able to send and retrieve files from SharePoint.
2. I will need some way of activating a macro within the retrieved Excel file from SharePoint.
3. It should support phones and tablets.

I'm currently using PowerApps, but the lack of features, and especially lack of custom coding makes it really difficult to use. It connects well with SharePoint, but I'm struggling to get the drawn image inside an excel file. I have made macros that can do it, but I have no way of automatically running the macros through PowerApps.

Comment: "`I'm trying to build an app`" ... for which operating system?

Comment: @Mawg Either an android or web application.

Comment: It would b ebetter to put that into your question.